# With a non-motorized telescope, can 100 pictures of 0.5 seconds be realigned and merged to get the equivalent of a 50-second long exposure shot?

Tags: telescope, photography, merger

I have a non-motorized Newton 130/900 telescope.

Of course, it's hopeless to do pictures with exposure ~ 1 minute. Even 1 second is probably too much, as seen in [Optimal exposure time for photography with unmotorized telescope](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/50707).

Instead of doing 1 long exposure photography of 50 seconds (which would produce star trailing), can we do:

- 100 automated photos of 0.5 second exposure time (each photo on its own has few star trailing)
- an algorithm can reposition each picture to compensate the movement of the earth
- at the end we merge the 100 (re-aligned) pictures to get a single picture.

It seems that, with this scenario, we get the same "number of photons" with these 100 photos, merged, as with a single 50-second-long exposure photo.

Is it a common practice?

Comment: You get the same number of signal photons, but also more noise.

Comment: @ProfRob Yes, noise due to the realignement (btw, is it just a translation + rotation or should it be a more complex geometrical transformation, like an homography ?).  Due to what else exactly ? Do you think it is still doable ?

Comment: You have a fixed readout noise in each picture.

Comment: @ProfRob Oh right. Is it a common practice for amateur astronomers? Is there a well-known freeware for this?

Comment: It's a great question and there are plenty of options for software to align sequential images. I am sure you'll either receive an excellent answer or three or it's possible someone might close this as duplicate of a similar question whose answers also answer your question. You can also search the [astrophotography tag in Photography SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrophotography) for software suggestions. And by the way, even motorized telescopes with alt/az mounts including major observatories have to deal with the fact that the FOV *rotates* about it's center over time

Comment: And before CCDs they had other solutions! [Did astronomers ever use photographic plate rotation along with alt-az mounts?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/47933/7982) But I digress... Anyway have a look at [Optimal exposure time for photography with unmotorized telescope](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/50691/7982)

Comment: @Basj  Is this what you're looking for?  https://astrobackyard.com/astrophotography-image-stacking-software/